# Would a redox reaction still happen between the two electrodes only connected by a wire?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

The galvanic cell I'm studying has Pb as reducing agent and Cu as oxidizing agent, and as I understand it the reason that the electron flows from the Pb electrode to the Cu electrode without anyone doing anything is because it's thermodynamically favorable, ie a spontaneous reaction. Would this flow of electron still happen if I only have two electrodes only connected by a wire? This doesn't seem possible, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You need some kind of charge neutraliser, i.e. a salt bridge (through which ions can travel in the opposite direction). Otherwise you would end up with a positively and a negatively charged macroscopic area which isn’t possible.

Comment: Also you would need an electrolyte for the Pb and Cu electrodes to be immersed in.